# Phonegap - javascript longpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, click

I've been trying for a while to make this work. This method seems to work a couple of places on the internet, but not for me. Notice that this works in Dreamweaver (and chrome), but not in Eclipse Indigo(Phonegap) when I try it out on my phone.

```
 $("#button4").mouseup(function(){
 //  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
    pressTimer = 0;
   // Clear timeout
   return false;
 }).mousedown(function(){
   // Set timeout
   pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { test(); },1000);
   return false; 
 });

 function test ()
 {alert("Longpress works");}
```

Normal "click" also works for "button4".

Comment: By "Doesn't work in eclipse" I assume you mean the built-in eclipse browser? Also, do you mean nothing happens or you get an error? What about the browsers with dev consoles like FF/Chrome? Any exceotions in the console?

Comment: Well, it works in Dreamweaver and Google Chrome. 
Transferred it to Eclipse and "Run as".. and then used my Phone for testing purposes. (Doesn't work in emulator either though). 
Everything else works except that code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this works for me. using on() is the newest way to implement jquery events

```
var longpress;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#yourElement").on('mousedown' ,function(){      
 longpress=true;    
 setTimeout(function() {    
    if(longpress)
     alert("long press works!");         
                  }, 3000);
})
$("#yourElement").on('mouseup' ,function(){      
    longpress=false;    
})

 }); //END
```

using .off() removes the event. Also notice that if you are using a smartphone you should use 'touchstart' as mousedown event and 'touchend' as mouseup.

Comment: That was my problem! mousedown/mouseup doesn't work on phone. Touchstart and touchend works! Thanks!